# bootsrap3 problems with float

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, css-float, twitter-bootstrap-3

http://pytools.webfactional.com/learn/bomar4/

Ive been working with bootstrap for redesigning a webpage for my internship this summer and after getting several layouts from my boss im hoping this the final one. i've had to scrap using templates because it was too difficult to overwrite some of the pre-defined themes they would implement so i more or less drew up this layout from scratch.

I'm having some issues with the floats of the divs with "mainContent" class and the divs with the "sideFooter" class. on F/S view the highlights table is supposed to appear flush under the main sidebar navigation, but it does not do this as there is a gap equal to the height of the panel box and I can't seem to figure out why... i followed other questions on here regarding setting floats to right for the content and float:left for the sidebar which moves to the bottom on small window resize, as in width < 768 px

also it looks pretty sloppy at certain breakpoints, with the bottom most footer not staying fixed to the left side on resize and expanding beyond the rest of the sidebar and also moving underneath the content at even smaller before reaching mobile size, which seems to look tolerable...

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: well this is looking worse and worse on resize through trial and error.... now im wondering if theres any way to lock the div's and prevent them from resizing at all temporarily until i can solve this problem...

Answer (score 0):

You may want to make 2 container divs, one for the sidebar and one for the main content.
e.g.

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col col-lg-3 col-sm-3">
         <!--All sidebar content Here --> 
     </div>
     <div class="col col-lg-9 col-sm-9">
         <!--All Main Content Here -->
     </div>
</div>
```

If you want the certain things on the sidebar to line up with certain items in the main content instead place those things that need to be aligned in rows together. For example:

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col col-lg-3 col-sm-3">
         <!--Aligning sidebar content Here --> 
     </div>
     <div class="col col-lg-9 col-sm-9">
         <!--Aligning Main Content Here -->
     </div>
</div>    
<div class="row">
     <div class="col col-lg-3 col-sm-3">
         <!--Aligning sidebar content Here --> 
     </div>
     <div class="col col-lg-9 col-sm-9">
         <!--Aligning Main Content Here -->
     </div>
</div>
```